# Sentiment Analysis with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sentiment-analysis

Any one with sentient analysis experience with `liblinear` algorithm. Any one have used [liblinear-ruby-swig](https://github.com/tomz/liblinear-ruby-swig) gem?

Please suggest me something to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used lib linear a lot for other classification not for sentiment analysis 
Are you interested in using lib linear or to do sentiment analysis? 
For simple sentiment analysis look at
https://chrismaclellan.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-of-tweets-using-ruby

Answer (score 2):

sad_panda gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/sad_panda) is similar to an R library I have used in the past.  It has tools for both polarity and emotion classification of text (as "sadness", "anger", "joy", a few others).

Answer (score 1):

There is not much work in ruby for sentiment analysis or machine learning in general. One of the best machine learning library is [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), so you can consider using it with jruby.

That said I have created an entry level [gem](https://github.com/malavbhavsar/sentimentalizer), I am planning to enhance it by porting some of the weka algorithms in ruby.